# Undefined method Class `all' in Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, grape-api

I have been following various Ruby on rails REST API tutorials, specifically those using the GRAPE gem. On all these attempts, I have been encountering a undefined method `all' error. I am new to RoR and have been relying on the generators for model generation. Here is the error and code in question:

undefined method `all' for API::V1::EmailAuth:Class

```
module API
  module V1
  class EmailAuth < Grape::API
    version 'v1' # path-based versioning by default
    format :json # We don't like xml anymore

    resource :email_auth do
      desc "Return list of email_auth"
      get do
        EmailAuth.all # obviously you never want to call #all here
      end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The file structure can be seen here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1A9oU.jpg
(My rep is too low to post images)

This is my first time actually posting something in stackoverflow, do let me know if I can refine the question.

Just a note: I have refered to [Undefined method `all' for ActiveSupport in Rails 4.0.0 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18117137/undefined-method-all-for-activesupport-in-rails-4-0-0-app?newreg=c08ebee99f20439cb9a9ecc0e9dc6174) and various similar questions regarding namespace issues, but can seem to resolve this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a class `Grape::API::EmailAuth` and in this class you want to load the active record class `EmailAuth`, then you need to reference it by two colons:

```
get do
  ::EmailAuth.all
end
```

Comment: Thank you, it works perfectly! I knew i missed something basic. I'll upvote you once my rep allows it